# Timespan in an if else statement

Tags: c#

I have the following code, and I am planning to use it to check if the user has placed a correct number of days between two `datetimepickers`.
I've searched on google, and some posts say use `var`, some say `parse`, and still it wont work, the message box won't pop up upon checking.

I have already made it work by using a label as a container of the result and use an if else statement to check if the text is equal to 14,15 or 16. It works cause i only need to detect if its 14, 15 or 16, but what if i was given a situation where i need to compare large numbers, I wish I a better solution than what i have right now.

Can someone please tell me how to compare time spans in an if else statement properly? Thank you so much. have a nice day :)

```
DateTime dateFrom = from_dtPicker.Value;
DateTime dateTo = to_dtPicker.Value;
TimeSpan DayDifference = dateTo - dateFrom;
double NumberOfDays = DayDifference.TotalDays;

if ((NumberOfDays < 14) && (NumberOfDays > 16)) 
{
    //message box
}
```

Here's what i mean with my weird solution though,

```
DateTime dateFrom = pp_from_dtPicker.Value;
DateTime dateTo = pp_to_dtPicker.Value;
TimeSpan DayDifference = dateTo - dateFrom;
numofdaysLBL.Text = DayDifference.TotalDays.ToString();

if ((numofdaysLBL.Text != "14") && (numofdaysLBL.Text != "15") && (numofdaysLBL.Text != "16"))
{
        //msgbox
}
```

Comment: your if statement reads as "if number of days less then 14 and **simultaneously** greater then 16". Which number is less then 14 **and** greater then 16?

Comment: _"using a label as a container"_ can you show us this code also, please?

Comment: what im trying to tell in my code is that `if (14 < NumberOfDays < 16) { msgbox.show(msh here); }` , is `if ((NumberOfDays < 14) && (NumberOfDays > 16)) ` wrong? im not really sure. okay let me edit and post my other weird but working solution for the moment.

Comment: `14 < NumberOfDays < 16` == `(14 < NumberOfDays) && (NumberOfDays < 16)` == `(NumberOfDays > 4) && (NumberOfDays < 16)`

Comment: ooops now that i re-read my comment i explained it the wrong way, if the days are 14,15 and 16 the messagebox `should not` pop up, only when NumberOfDays is not 14,15 or 16, thats when the messagebox should pop up, im really sorry.

Comment: but thank you for the explanation though.

Comment: you are welcome:) if you need other numbers, you can check this: `if ((NumberOfDays < 14) || (NumberOfDays > 16)) { msgbox.show("msh here"); }`

Comment: Also it is unclear of what you trying to achieve. I understand your question as "the user selects 2 dates: `dateFrom` and` dateTo`, you only need to show a message box if there are a certain number of days between these dates", am I right?

Comment: heeeeey, my dumb self taught that there's something really wrong with the whole code, it's just the `||` that i missed. gosh thank you so much :)

Comment: yes, correct, only if there is 14 or 15 or 16 days between the dates, anything less or more the msg box pops up.

Comment: I updated with my answer and now you can achieve it in cleaner way.

Comment: @vasily.sib, please review my answer as it is more cleaner way to achieve what OP suggested in his new edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me, that your comparison is the problem here

```
if ((NumberOfDays < 14) && (NumberOfDays > 16))
```

NumberOfDays can never be less than 14 AND more than 16 at the same time. Instead invert the comparison:

```
if ((NumberOfDays >= 14) && (NumberOfDays <= 16))
```

EDIT: Maybe I misunderstood what you are asking (as pointed out in the comments). If you want a more generic solution for comparing dates, you can simply wrap your code into a function

```
bool AreDatesClose(DateTime d1, DateTime d2, double minDaysApart, double maxDaysApart)
{
    var timespan = d1 - d2;
    return timespan.TotalDays >= minDaysApart && timespan.TotalDays <= maxDaysApart;
}
```

Comment: 14 and 16 are constant, I guess OP wants to have generic solution to check given date in a range

Comment: the question was not about this

Comment: @user1781290 if you read one more sentence (_"It **works** ..,  I wish I a better solution than what i have right now. Can someone please tell me how to compare time spans in an if else statement properly?"_) - you will see, that the question you answered is actualy just a typo.

Comment: @vasily.sib I added to the answer, just to be sure. Thank you

Comment: I guess new edit, I already answered it... But sadly didn't get recognize by OP

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function which will give you that `NumberOfDays` is in between given range or not

```
public bool IsGivenDateInRange(double numberOfDays, double startDate, double endDate)
{
  return numberOfDays >= startDate && numberOfDays <= endDate;
}
```

Now use this function in if condition

```
if(IsGivenDateInRange(NumberOfDays, 14, 16)) //Instead of 14 and 16 you can use any number
{
      //Your logic
}
```

As per new edit in your question if you want to show message box when date does not come in these range, then you can use same function but with **negation**

```
if(!IsGivenDateInRange(NumberOfDays, 14, 16)) //Instead of 14 and 16 you can use any number
{
      //MessageBox.Show();
      //Your logic
}
```